# Problemas con union y limit en un solo campo en mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Como puedo corregir la siguiente consulta

```
select ef.Proveedor, (select -- CONCAT(' ',rns.Nombres,rns.PrimerApellido,rns.SegundoApellido) 
CONCAT(TRIM(rns.`Nombres`), " ",TRIM(rns.`PrimerApellido`) , " " ,TRIM(rns.`SegundoApellido`)) 
from Ruc rc 
INNER JOIN RucN rns on rc.IdNit = rns.IdNit
where ef.Proveedor = rc.Nit limit 1
UNION 
select rj.RazonSocial from Ruc rcx  
INNER JOIN RucJ rj on rj.IdNit= rcx.IdNit
where ef.Proveedor = rcx.Nit limit 1) as nombrecliente,
ef.NumAprob,sum(ef.Monto),sum(ef.Montox),ef.Fecha_emision,count(ef.Proveedor),
MONTH(ef.Fechaemision) 
from sit.Ex_Facturas ef
where ef.Monto_Exonerado>=500000
and year(ef.Fechaemision)=2018 and month(ef.Fechaemision)=1 
GROUP BY ef.Proveedor;
```

Me muestra el siguiente error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'UNION.

Esto me funcionaba antes cuando la version era `mysql` pero se migro a `mariadb`

Comment: Pero tu consulta de arriba treara mas columnas que la de abajo? y de distimto tipo

Comment: le faltan unos parentesis en el segundo select... las dos consultas deben devolver la misma cantidad de columnas, pero el segundo select esta mal formado para el nombre de campo y las dos consultas no devuelven lo mismo. Que es lo que trataste de hacer?

Comment: el union es para un unico campo que es nombrecliente la cantidad de parametros esta bien

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué le das un alias a la tabla que parecería ser una sub-consulta: `nombrecliente`? ¿Si pruebas la sub-consulta aislada funciona? ¿Si pruebas la otra parte aislada funciona? Yo veo una lógica confusa en lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el nombre del cliente se puede obtener de dos tablas